How to turn bun.js async call into sync?
I need to turn async function running in the bun.js engine into sync one.
Reason: large codebase depends on existing sync implementation of the getData function. It needs to be evolved and utilise some async features, but its signature should be kept sync for backward compatibility.
It's impossible to do with JS. The way I see how to implement it:

The main JS process starts WebWorker in background that listen on net port.
The getData uses execSync to call curl to send request to WebWorker port, to call async function getDataNewWay and get back the response.

Probably the simplest solution, but the overhead is large.
Wonder if there's better way? Like:

Using unix named pipes and readFileSync/writeFileSync?
Using bun ffi to call some C/C++ system library, to do the networking call (same as with execSync and curl, but more efficient)?
There are advanced C Node.js extensions like fibers that do exactly that, but I would like to avoid heavily altering the JS engine, as it may cause unexpected bugs.
XMLHttpRequest in sync mode (seems like it's not supported in bun)?
Using Python FFI integration with bun, and make HTTP call via executing Python code requests.get(url) (package deno_python but it seems to also work with bun).

Example:
// The API `getData` that should be kept backward compatible
function getData(key: string): string {
  if (key == 'old_key') return getDataOldWay(key)
  return callSync('getDataNewWay', [key])
}

// The possible implementation
function getDataOldWay(key: string): string {
  return 'some data'
}
async function getDataNewWay(key: string): Promise<string> {
  return 'some data'
}
globalThis.getDataNewWay = getDataNewWay

function callSync<T>(fname: string, args: any[]): any {
  const code = `await globalThis.${fname}(...${JSON.stringify(args)})`
  return child_process.execSync(`http://localhost:3000/eval=${code}`).toString()
}

With Python extension it could be done as
import { python } from "bunpy"
const urllib = python.import("urllib.request")

function fetchUrlSync(url: string): string {
  // This code will be executed via FFI call to Python interpeter
  return urllib.urlopen(url).read().toString()
}
console.log(fetchUrlSync("http://example.com"))

and the callSync then will be:
function callSync(fname: string, args: any[]): any {
  const code = `await globalThis.${fname}(...${JSON.stringify(args)})`
  return fetchUrlSync(`http://localhost:3000/eval=${code}`)
}


deasync<T>(p: Promise<T>): T { - the fact that you want your "magical code" to work with a Promise means it is doomed to failure. A promise is async - and that's all it ever is

@Bravo thanks, good point, I updated the code.

but getDataNewWay is still async

@Bravo of course, it will stay async, the getDataNewWay will be synced via executing it remotely on another JS VM as async, but then getting its result over network synchronoysly. It's possible to make it sync inplace, in same JS VM with advanced C++ JS extension libraries like fibers, but as I said this may introduce bugs.

It's possible to make it sync inplace - I must not understand async/sync the same way you do, but that sounds like black magic. For it to "be synced" requires knowledge of an indeterminate future.

@Brawo check this 10y old node.js code https://github.com/al6x/synchronize/blob/master/examples/list.js. It uses async versions of node IO, and it's also don't block the loop. The magic is - fibers node.js plugin, an extension to JS VM.

"What's better?" basically means "Run some benchmark tests", which you should be able to do yourself (as I don't think many people will have a lot of experience with an "interesting" setup like this). Also, fibers has long been deprecated.

OK, if it works with large codebase depends on existing sync implementation then I guess it's a solution.
